# Android API for C++ applications to detect mobile network connection status

Tags: android, c++

I am totally new to android development. There is an android app written in C++ (not by me!). It does audio calls over mobile network. I need the application to detect network loss or subsequent network recovery (and then take necessary actions). I came across connectivity manager in this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type). It has callbacks which is perfect for me but they are in Kotlin and Java. Are there any such alternatives for C++?

Comment: Just use the java apis through jni?